# create_all method on database object not creating database tables

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a very basic Flask/SqlAlchemy project with one route located here.

https://github.com/thenetimp/flask_base_v2

In the route, I create a user object from the User model, but when I call the route I get the following error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such 
table: user
[SQL: INSERT INTO user (email_address, password, first_name, last_name, created_on, updated_on) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]
[parameters: ('jdoe@gmail.com', b'$2b$12$emg2oQcGeK0LEg5IFgie8eOEn2MJ/gKzyGWRPqOGJcQqlM1kCyskK', 'John', 'Doe', '2019-05-05 01:12:29.339788', '2019-05-05 01:12:29.339805')]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

In the app factory `create_app()` function I am calling `db.create_all()` to update the database and create the table, but it doesn't.  Other stack overflow questions with similar problems say that the wrong db reference is being used, but I do not know how to fix it so I am using the right reference.

I have searched stackoverflow, but the answers to similar questions haven't helped my use case/app structure (which I would like to keep intact if possible).

If someone could take a look I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an example from an article that used this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()

class User(Base):
```

to declare the class.  However, this didn't attach the model to the database instance.  Changing the class declaration to extend `db.Model` fixed the problem.